# Getting error while connecting dbt with postgres

Tags: postgresql, connection, dbt

I'm trying to connect my dbt project with postgres db.

I'm writing all the connecting credentials in profiles.yml but it is throwing below error when i am running dbt debug.

dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

> type object 'PostgresConnectionManager' has no attribute 'retry_connection'

I'm unable to find solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

dbt-core v1.2.0 has added retry_connection method in BaseConnectionManager to support the retry connection feature. If the adapter implements this method, it can't run on dbt-core v1.1.0. Try updating the adapter.